# How do NServiceBus endpoint names work with pub/sub

Tags: configuration, nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I have been fighting the same very simple problem with NServiceBus all day today. The problem is that there is lots of documentation on how to change the configuration, but almost nothing that helps me to know what configuration I need.

There are sample applications, and they work, but there is nothing explaining how they work, what limitations they have, or how to do something just a little bit different than the sample. The sample applications also present a "Hello world" type simplicity, and in any real application you need something different from the sample application, but again there is no help on how to make these changes, or the implications of configuration choices.

From all the things that are very difficult to guess from the documentation, it is the relationship between the endpoint name, the UnicastBusConfig mappings, and pub/sub persistence that is causing the most frustration right now.

Is the endpoint name the name of the MSMQ queue? Does that mean that every application has only one input queue for all message types? Does adding a mapping in UnicastBusConfig cause a subscription message to be sent to the publisher, or does it add a subscription record in subscription DB? Why can't you add the same message type more than once to UnicastBusConfig? Why can't I just subscribe to messages of a certain type without having to know which server they come from?

For someone that understands NServiceBus this probably seems so simple that it wasn't worth documenting, but for someone coming to this for the first time, it's the very simple stuff that's the most difficult to infer from the morass of low level detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the endpoint name the name of the MSMQ queue?

Yes.

> Does that mean that every application has only one input queue for all message types?

Yes. Each endpoint has a single queue associated with it, so all messages for that endpoint go through the same queue.

> Does adding a mapping in UnicastBusConfig cause a subscription message to be sent to the publisher, or does it add a subscription record in subscription DB?

Neither really. The UnicastBusConfig section is for setting up the relationship between types (or assemblies) and endpoints.  So it doesn't actually cause a subscription to be set up (per se), but it tells the framework where the messages will be coming from (and therefore *how* to subscribe to them).

The actual subscription gets created when the system starts up and NSB finds a handler for a particular type of message that matches a section in the UnicastBusConfig (assuming auto-subscribing is turned on).

This also works for sending Commands--the config section lets the framework know to which endpoint to Send() a Command.

> Why can't you add the same message type more than once to UnicastBusConfig?

Because a Command can have only one (logical) endpoint that handles it, and an Event can have only one (logical) endpoint that publishes it.

> Why can't I just subscribe to messages of a certain type without having to know which server they come from?

This question is a bit more difficult to answer definitively, as it gets into the philosophy of having a central broker (hub and spoke) vs. bus-style architecture.

But in a nutshell, something, somewhere needs to know how to find the publisher in order to subscribe to it.  Because NServiceBus does not have a central broker or routing table, it is left to the client to be configured with knowledge of the endpoints it consumes.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Unfortunately I think this means that NServiceBus is not the right solution for me, and maybe this is why I experienced so much frustration with it.

Comment: Feel free to post on the mailing list--getting help with your particular situation may benefit from more of a back-and-forth conversation than SO can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the NServiceBus documentation at http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/, it's quite comprehensive and should provide answers to most of your questions.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/how-pub-sub-works?

Comment: I spent most of the day reading this documentation and experimenting with the code. This is the "morass of detail" I referred to in my original question.
The problem with the documentation is that every article assumes that you already read every other article, which means that you have to go around and around the loop gradually building up context, and gradually understanding more, just to get to the fundamental principals which could easily be covered off in an introduction or getting started type article.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same things. And I'm integrating with Azure too, so I feel your pain.

Comment: It seems to be a very common problem. Libraries and services often have some very high level abstract concepts described, then a huge amount of detail on thousands individual methods at the very bottom of the stack, but lack any documentation on how these thousands of tiny pieces realize the high level concepts.